# How can I fire $forceUpdate in Vue3 compositionAPI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

There is no `this` in composition API. How can we fire `$forceUpdate()` like what we can do in option API in Vue2? Thanks!

Comment: you can't, it's not available in the context object.  What would you use this for?  There's almost always a better way to trigger an update with Vue's reactivity system.